# Delete entries from CSV from second CSV file

Tags: bash, macos, csv, terminal

I am trying to delete entries found in first.csv from second.csv

My first.csv looks like that:

```
surname,lastname,,,website-link,country,None,city,,,email,,,phonenumber,,,,
```

My second.csv contains only email-adresses. So I want to delete all matching emails in first.csv.

Example:

first.csv:

```
mike,pence,,,www.google.de,germany,None,Berlin,,,mike@pence.de,,,01769921323,,,,
frank,schwarz,,,www.bund.de,germany,None,München,,,frank@google.de,,,01469425323,,,,
```

second.csv:

```
frank@google.de
```

Output (first.csv) should be:

```
mike,pence,,,www.google.de,germany,None,Berlin,,,mike@pence.de,,,01769921323,,,,
```

Can I achieve that via mac terminal?

Comment: Do you want to delete the whole record or just the email address? Did you try anything?

Comment: What about iterating the first one to list all the mail adresses (with a regex), then replace in the second one, the lines found for each?

Comment: @JamesBrown I want to delete the whole record, I tried a lot of things found here but didn't work with my case

Comment: @Larme sorry I don't now how to exactly do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using awk to read both files

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR {mail[$1]=1} NR !=FNR { if (mail[$11]!=1) { print $0 } }' csvb csva
```

When processing the second file (csvb) - NR=FNR, build an array mail, indexed with the email address and the value 1. Then when processing the first file (csva) - NR!=FNR, if there is not an entry for the email address ($11) in the mail array, print the line, otherwise don't

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -F, '          # using awk, set field separator
NR==FNR {            # process first file named second
    a[$1]            # hash email address
    next             # proces the next record from the first file
}                    # beyond this point process second file name first
!($11 in a)          # if email address in second file not in the first file, output
' second first
```

Output:

```
surname,lastname,,,website-link,country,None,city,,,email,,,phonenumber,,,,
mike,pence,,,www.google.de,germany,None,Berlin,,,mike@pence.de,,,01769921323,,,,
```